# How do I delete a homegroup if I am not in it?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8, network-shares, homegroup

So a while ago I made a homegroup on my network. The computer I made it on is now formatted. I don't have any computers on the network in the group.

When I try to enter the homegroup it asks me for a password. How do I delete the homegroup? The files on it do not matter.

Comment: Do you have access to the computers that were on the homegroup? If all computers "Leave the homegroup" it will no longer exist.

Comment: Well, I formatted the only computer on it, so yes.

Comment: Have you tried "leave the homegroup" option?

Comment: Well, I'm not in it, so no. Like I said the *only* computer in there is formatted into another computer (and another OS)

Comment: Just as a "wipe it off the list of culprates", have you rebooted your router in this process? if not, could you and update if anything has changed? If you have formated, installed new os(win8) and no comuter at all exist iin the home group, the router is the next likly items that could relate to the issue. If this addresses it, i will post an answer to that point.